# appcelerator drawer menu is not working

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i have used the **com.alcoapps.drawermenu module** to implement drawer menu functionality.It's working fine with appcelerator sdk version 4.0.0. But when I upgraded the version of appcelerator sdk to 5.3.1, it gives the runtime error.

[following is the runtime error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvRP3.png)

```
  [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [655,655] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
  [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,655] - In ti:/view.js:19,10
  [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,655] - Message: Uncaught Error: Cannot add window/tabGroup to a view.
  [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,655] - Source:           throw new Error("Cannot add window/tabGroup to a view.");
  [ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/view.js:19: Uncaught Error: Cannot add window/tabGroup to a view.
```

after debugging i have found out the sourcs of error which is

```
   $.drawermenu.init({
    menuview : menu,
    mainview : main,
    duration : 200,
    parent : thisWin
});
```

I have gone through [this](https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/alloy-widget-drawermenu/blob/master/README.md) documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, a Window cannot be added to a View.

If you look at the [demo](https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/alloy-widget-drawermenu/tree/master/demo/app) you can see the module uses Views instead of Windows. You should too!

So transform your `<Window>` tags to `<View>` tags and all should work again.